# Why my array does not sort correctly

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have two arrays `$men`, `$sub` , I want want to sort them with this condition: `if($men["titre"] == $sub["menuParent"])` I put the content of the second array that contains $sub["menuParent"] in the first one.

Case:

```
//Array1 ($menu)

array(3) {
  ["menu1"] => array(3) {
    ["titre"] => string(6) "Title2"
    ["lien"] => string(0) ""
    ["order"] => string(1) "2"
  }
  ["menu2"] => array(3) {
    ["titre"] => string(6) "Title3"
    ["lien"] => string(10) "google.com"
    ["order"] => string(1) "3"
  }
  ["menu3"] => array(3) {
    ["titre"] => string(6) "Title1"
    ["lien"] => string(0) ""
    ["order"] => string(1) "1"
  }
}

//Array2 ($submenu)

array(3) {
  ["submenu1"] => array(3) {
    ["titre"] => string(9) "SubTitle2"
    ["menuParent"] => string(6) "Title2"
    ["order"] => string(1) "2"
  }
  ["submenu2"] => array(3) {
    ["titre"] => string(9) "SubTitle3"
    ["menuParent"] => string(6) "Title2"
    ["order"] => string(1) "3"
  }
  ["submenu3"] => array(3) {
    ["titre"] => string(9) "SubTitle1"
    ["menuParent"] => string(6) "Title1"
    ["order"] => string(1) "1"
  }
}
```

Here for exemple in:

**array1** `["menu1"]["titre"] => string(6) "Title2"`

**array2**   `["submenu1"]["menuParent"] => string(6) "Title2"`

Now while `["menu1"]["titre"]` & `["submenu1"]["menuParent"]` values are the same `"Title2"`, So I push :

```
["submenu1"] => array(3) {
    ["titre"] => string(9) "SubTitle2"
    ["menuParent"] => string(6) "Title2"
    ["order"] => string(1) "2"
}
```

in:

```
["menu1"] => array(3) {
    ["titre"] => string(6) "Title2"
    ["lien"] => string(0) ""
    ["order"] => string(1) "2"
  }
```

as child like this:

```
array(3) {
  ["menu1"] => array(3) {
    ["titre"] => string(6) "Title2"
    ["lien"] => string(0) ""
    ["order"] => string(1) "2"
    ["child"] => array(3) {
      [0] => array(3) {
        ["titre"] => string(9) "SubTitle2"
        ["menuParent"] => string(6) "Title2"
        ["order"] => string(1) "2"
      }
  }
```

So I do all this for whole elements`

Here is my try, but It push all the elements in `["menu2"]` instead of `["submenu1"]`, `["submenu2"]` IN `["menu1"]` and `["submenu3"]` IN `["menu3"]`

**My Try:**

```
/*Injection submenu to Menu*/
foreach($menu as $men) {
    foreach($submenu as $sub) {
        if($men["titre"] == $sub["menuParent"]){
        $key = key($menu);
        $menu[$key]['child'][] = array($sub["titre"], $sub["menuParent"], $sub["order"]);
        //My array_push doesn't work also
        array_push($menu, array($sub["titre"], $sub["menuParent"], $sub["order"]))
        }

    }
}
```

**Result:**

```
array(3) {
  ["menu1"] => array(3) {
    ["titre"] => string(6) "Title2"
    ["lien"] => string(0) ""
    ["order"] => string(1) "2"
  }
  ["menu2"] => array(4) {
    ["titre"] => string(6) "Title3"
    ["lien"] => string(10) "google.com"
    ["order"] => string(1) "3"
    ["child"] => array(3) {
      [0] => array(3) {
        [0] => string(9) "SubTitle2"
        [1] => string(6) "Title2"
        [2] => string(1) "2"
      }
      [1] => array(3) {
        [0] => string(9) "SubTitle3"
        [1] => string(6) "Title2"
        [2] => string(1) "3"
      }
      [2] => array(3) {
        [0] => string(9) "SubTitle1"
        [1] => string(6) "Title1"
        [2] => string(1) "1"
      }
    }
  }
  ["menu3"] => array(3) {
    ["titre"] => string(6) "Title1"
    ["lien"] => string(0) ""
    ["order"] => string(1) "1"
  }
}
```

Where I'm at fault, If anyone can explain to me why and if I took the good way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is where your picking the key up, you can use the `foreach ( as $key->$value)` method to get the key of each item (`foreach` works on it's own copy of the array and so picking the key from the original array isn't the same as the current one).  Also you could use &$men, the & allows you to alter the original array element rather than create a new entry and trying to push the new element into the array...

```
foreach($menu as $key => $men) {
    foreach($submenu as $key1=>$sub) {
        if($men["titre"] == $sub["menuParent"]){
            $menu[$key]['child'][$key1] = array($sub["titre"], $sub["menuParent"], $sub["order"]);
        }

    }
}
```

gives...

```
Array
(
    [menu1] => Array
        (
            [titre] => Title2
            [lien] => 
            [order] => 2
            [child] => Array
                (
                    [submenu1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => SubTitle2
                            [1] => Title2
                            [2] => 2
                        )

                    [submenu2] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => SubTitle3
                            [1] => Title2
                            [2] => 3
                        )

                )

        )

    [menu2] => Array
        (
            [titre] => Title3
            [lien] => google.com
            [order] => 3
        )

    [menu3] => Array
        (
            [titre] => Title1
            [lien] => 
            [order] => 1
            [child] => Array
                (
                    [submenu3] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => SubTitle1
                            [1] => Title1
                            [2] => 1
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

**Update:**

Code using `&$men`, note that in setting the data it no longer uses the key, but uses the $men variable.

```
foreach($menu as &$men) {
    foreach($submenu as $key=>$sub) {
        if($men["titre"] == $sub["menuParent"]){
            $men['child'][$key] = array($sub["titre"], $sub["menuParent"], $sub["order"]);
        }
    }
}
unset($men);  // Good practice to ensure reference is reset
```

Comment: Yes, I was missing the `key` of the foreach, now it works, but even without the `&` in `$men` it works also, I didn't undestand what is the difference between ? I added it, it also works but it added me `&`in the last one like this : `["menu3"] => &array(4)` what does it mean ? Last think : do know how to conserve the keys values of the added I mean instead of exemple `[0] => SubTitle3` `["submenu2"] => SubTitle3`

Comment: Sorry, it was probably a bit confusing, I've added a version of the code which uses the & version.

Comment: It works fine, thanks for your time Even the `$` remains a little vague for me but it works. I am asking myself why the `$men['child'][$key] = ...` works with `&$men` but not without ? and with `$key=>$men` works if I change `$men['child'][$key] =` to `$menu[$key]['child'][$key2] =`?